# Difference between select from a whole partition or from table with small dataset?

Tags: sql-server, performance, t-sql, sql-server-2008, partitioning

I am new to partitioning.

Would be there a **difference in performance** between

```
select * from my_partitionedData where date = '20110523'
```

and

```
select * from my_Data where date = '20110523'
```

where `my_partitionedData` is a table partitioned by `date` by 1 day and `my_Data` is a table which has only data for `'20110523'` and both tables have same structure?

The other question - would be there a difference in performance in running these selects if all the partitions of the `my_partitionedData` are in the **same file group**? (note - the select is always for 1 day)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like everything else in SQL, you will need to test to be sure.

That being said, I think you should get identical performance.

Behind the scenes, a partitioned table is basically a lot of smaller tables logically unioned together.  If you are partitioning by day in you partitioned table, and your non-part table has only one day of data, the execution plan and performance should be pretty much identical.

Comment: "Behind the scenes, a partitioned table is basically a lot of smaller tables logically unioned together" - I think the same but want a confirmation from a guru who knows this for fact.

Comment: @Bobb - I'm telling you it is :)  I have done a ton of testing with this.  See my question a few months back here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5472689/sql-server-2008-partitioning-and-clustered-indexes

Comment: @Bobb - to further elaborate - I tested all kinds of performance on a huge partitioned table (800m records, about 600 GB of data an 1TB of indexes) for just such a scenario.  I'm still doing more testing on aggregation currently.

Comment: thank you. that what I wanted to hear :) would you agree with my strategy - I want to use partitioning to rid off the indexes (except clustered PKs of course). Because all the queries are for 1 day I want to not use indexes as a query by 1 day runs fast enough. And if each partition will have 1 day of data it should be OK. (dont ask why this way :))

Comment: If partitioning gives you a small enough result set that you don't need additional indexes, super.  Bear in mind if your use changes some things are significantly poorer performing on partitioned tables. In my experience the worst were range scans and aggregation.  Aggregation was atrocious.

Answer (score 0):

If one returns the same data set a partitioned and non-partitioned table will return the data with the same IO.  If the partitioned table has less fragmentation there would be a reduction in the IO delay from a random seek of the disk heads to retrieve the pages but all in all 100k of data is 100k of data.

You did not mention if you were considering partitioning the index.  Partitioning index is an excellent way to reduce the number of levels which must be traversed to find the location of the data row.  Partitioning indexes and tables with the same function is the optiomal solution.

Answer (score -2):

> where my_partitionedData is a table
>   partitioned by date by 1 day and
>   my_Data is a table which has only data
>   for '20110523' and both tables have
>   same structure?

The later one will less access time.

> The other question - whould be there a
>   difference in performance in running
>   these selects if all the partitions of
>   the my_partitionedData are in the same
>   file group? (note - the select is
>   always for 1 day)

The access time will be more in this case despite of 1 day data.

Partitioning is required to improve the scalability and manageability of large tables and tables that have varying access patterns.

You created two tables to store information about each day records and on the other hand a single table for each day data is the easiest to design and understand, but these tables are not necessarily optimized for performance, scalability, and manageability, particularly as the table grows larger.

Comment: > The later one will less access time. - Why?

Comment: As you said in the above comments "where my_partitionedData is a table partitioned by date by 1 day and my_Data is a table which has only data for '20110523' and both tables have same structure?"   It contains data for a particular date .

Comment: As the OP said the later one will have data for a specific date only so definitely the access time will be less comparing to the former one which has all records.

Comment: a partitioned table would contain data for a particular date also, that is the purpose of partitioning (by date in this case), so why would you say it would access in less time?

Comment: If you read the OP question again there is a statement "and my_Data is a table which has only data for '20110523'". I hope it justifies my answer now.

Comment: @Pankaj - It explains but doesn't justify.  He's comparing to a partitioned table which should have essentially the same data.